# How to get row count using laravel fluent query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to get the row count using Laravel fluent query builder

I have attached the query I used to filter other data and also I need to get the row count.

Here is the database Table:-

[image]

```
  $results = DB::table('newsfeed_posts')
    ->select('newsfeed_posts.*', 'users.first_name as posted_user_first_name', 'users.last_name as posted_user_last_name', 'users.profile_image as posted_user_profile_image','proid.profile_image as posted_receiver_profile_image', 'timeline.first_name as post_receiver_first_name', 'timeline.last_name as post_receiver_last_name', 'timeline.office_branch_id as post_receiver_office_id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_sender_id')
    ->leftJoin('users as timeline', 'timeline.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id') 
    ->leftJoin('users as proid', 'proid.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id') 
    ->where('newsfeed_posts.deleted_status', '0')
    // ->where('newsfeed_posts.post_sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->groupBy('newsfeed_posts.id')
    ->orderBy('newsfeed_posts.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();

    return $results;
```

Comment: `$results` is a collection so use `$results->count();` anytime. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-count

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the filtered records from database with number of fetched items record. Then you can use firstly use get all results using `get()` function and on this result you can use `->count()` to get all fetched items  count.

```
$result = DB::table('newsfeed_posts')
    ->select('newsfeed_posts.*', 'users.first_name as posted_user_first_name', 'users.last_name as posted_user_last_name', 'users.profile_image as posted_user_profile_image','proid.profile_image as posted_receiver_profile_image', 'timeline.first_name as post_receiver_first_name', 'timeline.last_name as post_receiver_last_name', 'timeline.office_branch_id as post_receiver_office_id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_sender_id')
    ->leftJoin('users as timeline', 'timeline.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id') 
    ->leftJoin('users as proid', 'proid.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id') 
    ->where('newsfeed_posts.deleted_status', '0')
    // ->where('newsfeed_posts.post_sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->groupBy('newsfeed_posts.id')
    ->orderBy('newsfeed_posts.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();

return [
    'total' => $result->count(),
    'result' => $result
];
```

Comment: No I need to get row count as a variable then i can show the count on frontend

Comment: @Fed check now.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Laravel query builder, you may have to issue two separate queries:

```
$count = DB::table('newsfeed_posts')
    ->select('newsfeed_posts.*', 'users.first_name as posted_user_first_name', 'users.last_name as posted_user_last_name', 'users.profile_image as posted_user_profile_image','proid.profile_image as posted_receiver_profile_image', 'timeline.first_name as post_receiver_first_name', 'timeline.last_name as post_receiver_last_name', 'timeline.office_branch_id as post_receiver_office_id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_sender_id')
    ->leftJoin('users as timeline', 'timeline.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id') 
    ->leftJoin('users as proid', 'proid.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id') 
    ->where('newsfeed_posts.deleted_status', '0')
    ->where('newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->groupBy('newsfeed_posts.id')
    ->count();
```

Then, use your current query to generate the result set you want.

If you are using MySQL 8+ under the hood, then there is an alternative.  We can try using `COUNT()` as an analytic function, using just a single query:

```
$results = DB::table('newsfeed_posts')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt, newsfeed_posts.*', 'users.first_name as posted_user_first_name', 'users.last_name as posted_user_last_name', 'users.profile_image as posted_user_profile_image','proid.profile_image as posted_receiver_profile_image', 'timeline.first_name as post_receiver_first_name', 'timeline.last_name as post_receiver_last_name', 'timeline.office_branch_id as post_receiver_office_id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_sender_id')
    ->leftJoin('users as timeline', 'timeline.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id') 
    ->leftJoin('users as proid', 'proid.id', 'newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id') 
    ->where('newsfeed_posts.deleted_status', '0')
    ->where('newsfeed_posts.post_receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->groupBy('newsfeed_posts.id')
    ->orderBy('newsfeed_posts.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

The count over the entire result set (after `GROUP BY` aggregation) would then be available using the alias `cnt`.